# Comment « accuser » a-t-il évolué pour signifier « reconnaitre » ou « signaler » ?

Tags: étymologie

Je m’intéresse à son utilisation dans des expressions comme « accuser réception de ». Comment expliquer cette acception en général (sans restreindre la généralité) ?

Mal nommé, [le site web «  des expressions françaises décortiquées »](http://www.expressio.fr/expressions/accuser-reception.php) ne décortique ni son sens ni son étymologie; ce site n'en réitère que le sens, que je comprends déjà et dont je ne m’enquiers pas.

Answer (score 2):

Pour *accuser* le §3 du petit Robert, pour la locution citée :

> *Signaler, rendre manifeste* :
>
> - [Religion] Accuser ses péchés => *confesser*
> - *Accuser réception*  : donner avis qu'on a reçu.

et au §4 :

> - [Figuratif] *Indiquer, montrer, révéler* ... ; [Locution familière] *Accuser le coup* : montrer par ses réactions qu'on est affecté, physiquement ou moralement.

Il s'agit de remplir une obligation à laquelle on ne peut surseoir, sous peine d'être accusé de faux témoignage.

Alors que l'on pourrait *témoigner [de son plein gré] d'avoir reçu*, on est obligé (dans le cas d'une lettre recommandée par exemple) *d'accuser le coup*, cela nous engage moralement, voire juridiquement.